# Can you put corn cobs in a compost bin?

Tags: compost

Can you put corn cobs in a compost bin? They seem hard and tough, wondering if they'll break down. I assume that the husk will be just like any other green substance like grass?

Comment: Cob does not break down well. Bury near water.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If the cobs are left whole it will take a long time for them to break down but if you aren't concerned about that and want to just do the easiest thing, just toss them in and eventually they'll break down.

To speed that up, you'll need to increase the surface area of the cob material.  You could chop them up a bit and that would help speed things along.

I'm pretty lazy about the compost pile so if there are oversize pieces that aren't done breaking down yet, I'll sift those out and thrown them back in the pile.

Yeah, the husks are similar to leaves and have a higher nitrogen level. They break down really quickly in the pile if it is a hot pile.  The cobs though will take some time.